# Merge multiple files in multiple directories - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

We have a requirement to loop multiple directiories and in each directory there will be, multiple text files with Pattern File"n".txt which needs to merged to one, File.txt

We are using Bourne Shell scripting.

Example:

```
/staging/dusk/inbound/ --> Main Directory

Dir1
File1.txt,File2.txt,..sample1.doc,sample2.pdf,File*.txt  --> we have to Merge the File name which starts with Fil*.txt -->Final.txt

Dir2
File1.txt,File2.txt,..attach1.txt,sample1.doc, File*.txt --> we have to Merge the File name which starts with Fil*.txt -->Final.txt

Dir3
File1.txt,File2.txt,File*.txt,..sample1,sample2*.txt --> we have to Merge the File name which starts with Fil*.txt -->Final.txt

Dir4
File1.txt,File2.txt,File*.txt,..temp.doc,attach.txt --> we have to Merge the File name which starts with Fil*.txt -->Final.txt

Di5
File1.txt,File2.txt,File*.txt,..sample1,sample2*.txt --> we have to Merge the File name which starts with Fil*.txt -->Final.txt

Dir"n"
File1.txt,File2.txt,File3.txt,File*.txt..attach1,attach*.txt --> we have to Merge the File name which starts with Fil*.txt -->Final.txt
```

The files from each directory can be looped using 
cat *.txt > all.txt command.

But how we loop the directiories?

Comment: Maybe something like this oneliner? for i in Dir*; do (cd $i; cat File* > Final.txt); done

Comment: The `cd` is buggy and ugly. You want `for i in Dir*; do cat "$i"/File* >"$i"/Final.txt; done`

Comment: But I'm guessing the OP actually wants `cat Dir*/File* >Final.txt`

Answer (score 2):

To catenate `Fil*.txt` from all immediate subdirectories of the current directory,

```
cat */Fil*.txt >Final.txt
```

To access arbitrarily deeply nested subdirectories, some shells offer `**` as an extension, but this is not POSIX `sh` -compatible.

```
cat **/Fil*.txt >Final.txt
```

If you actually want to loop over your directories and do something more complex with each, that's

```
for d in */; do
    : something with "$d"
done
```

Or similarly, for shells which support `**`, you can loop over all directories within directories;

```
for d in **/; do
    : something with "$d"
done
```

For example, `: something with "$d"` could be `cat "$d"/Fil*.txt >"$d"/Final.txt` to create a `Final.txt` in each directory, which contains only the `Fil*.txt` files in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can probably try using the find command

```
find /staging/dusk/inbound/ -name "*.txt" -type f -exec cat {} \;>>MergedFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a ad-hok way

```
find /staging/dusk/inbound -type f -name *.txt | sort -n | awk '{ print "cat " $1 " >> all.txt"}' > marge.sh
chmod +x marge.sh
sh merge.sh
```

Comment: The temporary file is unnecessary; just pipe to `sh` instead of writing to a file. But this has multiple errors and unclarities. The `| -type f` is a syntax error, and why would you sort the results numerically? The `awk` script will break on file names which contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters. Etc etc.

Comment: find /staging/dusk/inbound -type f | sort -n | awk '{ print "cat " $1 " >> all.txt"}' > marge.sh
chmod +x marge.sh
sh merge.sh

Comment: Yes, my copy paste problem, I updated. And Please follow as I shared. sh file is unnecessary but at the beginning, it's important to monitor whats inside the bash file.

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48701498/edit) link which lets you edit your answer.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind explains some of the pitfalls with this approach. There are other pages on that site which you should probably also read, in particular https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: You are also failing to exclude files which don't match `Fil*.txt` -- this is of course easy to fix, but probably not worth the effort, given the other issues here.

Comment: Yes, @tripleee is right, my mistake I did not notice that example carefully. Please add your naming condition [ -name *.txt ] .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164810/discussion-between-kernelv5-and-tripleee).

Comment: The one redeeming feature here is calling the file [Marge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marge_Simpson).